# Are there ways to run Android on XWindows?

Tags: android, x11, xorg

I was wondering if there are ways to run Android on XWindows (Xorg) without any emulation and using X11 (or a window) to render graphics... I've read that Android uses the FB device (and I don't know how does this fit with OpenGl).

Does anyone have some information about this? Are there projects or other?

Comment: A resounding "no" was heard round the world.

Comment: ...I was just wondering, but it would be good nah?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around:
http://www.androidfanatic.com/community-forums.html?func=view&catid=9&id=1615